# Barplot by R, the scale (mark, correspond to labels) does not correspond to each bar?

Tags: r

But they are same length vector, I have tried many part of code, just can't let the "city name" correspond each bar? The problem of pdf width? Or I shouldn't `axis(1, c(1:47)`? Tried but don't solve...Reminder also will be grateful.

```
pdf("barplot1.pdf", width = 8.6, height = 8)  

matrix_tem <- t(matrix(each_bar_number))    #each_bar_number is a vector, length(each_bar_number) is 47
barplot(matrix_tem, ylim = c(0, 150), xaxt="n", border=NA, space = NULL, beside=F)
axis(1, c(1:47), labels=as.character(cityname_vector), las = 2,cex.axis = 0.6) #length(cityname_vector) is 47  

dev.off()
```

Comment: A reproducible question would help? I think barplot expects the names in the names.arg parameter - See http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-11-bar-charts/ for an example,

Comment: Exactly, names.arg is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

barplot() expects the names to be in the names.arg parameter inside the call to barplot. See [here](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-11-bar-charts/) for an example. Not sure why the axis labelling fails.

**## Default S3 method:**

```
 barplot(height, width = 1, space = NULL,
    names.arg = NULL, legend.text = NULL, beside = FALSE,
    horiz = FALSE, density = NULL, angle = 45,
    col = NULL, border = par("fg"),
    main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL,
    xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, xpd = TRUE, log = "",
    axes = TRUE, axisnames = TRUE,
    cex.axis = par("cex.axis"), cex.names = par("cex.axis"),
    inside = TRUE, plot = TRUE, axis.lty = 0, offset = 0,
    add = FALSE, args.legend = NULL, ...)
```

**Arguments**

```
 names.arg
   a vector of names to be plotted below each bar or group of bars.
   If this argument is omitted, then the names are taken from the
   names attribute of height if this is a vector, or the column 
   names if it is a matrix.
```